# where to see test code coverage for lwc jest Test

Tags: unit-test, lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I have this below test class which is testing a `getPicklistValues` method on a LWC component named manageCountries.

```
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import ManageCountries from 'c/ManageCountries';
import { getPicklistValues, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { registerLdsTestWireAdapter } from '@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest';

// Mock realistic data
const mockGetPicklistValues = require('./data/getPicklistValues.json');

const getRecordAdapter = registerLdsTestWireAdapter(getPicklistValues);

describe('c-manage-countries', () => {

    afterEach(() => {
        // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });

    it('wireMthodTest1', () => {
        const element = createElement('c-manage-countries', {
            is: ManageCountries
        });
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        getRecordAdapter.emit(mockGetPicklistValues);
    });
});
```

When I `npm run test:unit` and it works as expected with below message in the terminal

[image]

this message doesn't show the percentage covered, and can we see red and green lines just like we see in apex to know which lines are covered by test class and which ones are pending?

**Update**

JS for manageCountries component

```
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: STUDY_LOCATION_OBJECT }) objectInfo;

@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: SHIPPING_FREQUENCY_FIELD })
getShippingFrequencyOptions({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.shippingFrequencyOptions = data.values;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.objectInfo));
    } else if (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}
```

getting below error when running npm run test:unit:coverage without coverage npm run test:unit works fine

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use the command `npm run test:unit:coverage` (i.e., usage of flag `--coverage` in your test command or you may even update this in the `scripts` section of `package.json` config/ you may be familiar with this approach if you have worked in node or npm).

**--Update-(Start)--:**

Add the following to the `package.json`, if you don't have it already.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "npm run test:unit",
    "test:unit": "sfdx-lwc-jest",
    "test:unit:watch": "sfdx-lwc-jest --watch",
    "test:unit:debug": "sfdx-lwc-jest --debug",
    "test:unit:coverage": "sfdx-lwc-jest --coverage"
  }
```

**--Update-(End)--:**

[Or, you can configure the jest.config.js file for various coverage options as mentioned [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#collectcoverage-boolean). *Note: I've personally not tested using these config options but it should be possible*].

See the screenshot below for the percentage covered information in table format. The last column `Uncovered Line #s` shows the lines that were not covered in the unit test. This isn't similar to way it shows up for apex in Dev Console, but gets you the required information.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer npm run test:unit --coverage gives same result

Comment: in package.json, I edited "test": "npm run test:unit", to "test": "npm run test:unit --coverage", but still everything is same.

Comment: looks like the initial jest config and setup already does add this for you and the command should be `npm run test:unit:coverage`. Please check the update section at the and the updated command in my answer.

Comment: npm run test:unit this works fine but this npm run test:unit:coverage throws error and this npm run test:unit:coverage provides code coverage for all the LWC not the one which it is running for, could you please suggest

Comment: and I have the same values under scripts in package.json but still when I click on play button at top right corner it doesn't show code coverage.

Comment: Clicking the button at the top right in VS Code seems to always run `npm run test:unit` regardless. And, updating `"test": "npm run test:unit"` to `"test": "npm run test:unit --coverage"` seems to throw error for me too. I'll look into how to overcome this. **But, with the existing config in your package.json, if you explicitly run the command `npm run test:unit:coverage` in CLI directly, it seems to get the result.** I have the habit of running commands thru CLI  and hence, didn't get the error earlier.

Comment: in my case this one npm run test:unit:coverage also fails

Comment: Could you post the error message? Must be some config issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112346/discussion-between-gs650x-and-arut).